# ¿Cómo definir una variable automáticamente con un for?

Tags: javascript, html

Requiero generar variables automáticamente mediante un for! este es mi codigo

```js
  var con=["qqx1","rrx1","ssx1","ttx1","vvx1","www1","xxx1"];
            for(var k=1; k<=con.length;k++){
              for(var j=1;j<=5;j++){
                for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
                
                  console.log(con[k]+i+i);//hasta aqui todo va bien
                       //aqui mi problema que quiero que mi variable se llame igual que el id que estoy obteniendo
                     var (con[k]+i+i)=document.getElementById(con[k]+i+i).value;


                }
              }
            }
```

[image: Aqui me muestra las variables generadas en el navegador]

Comment: ¿ Variables locales a la función o ámbito, o globales ?

Comment: Porque no lo haces como un array?

Comment: Por poder, se puede hacer. Pero deberías plantearte si es una buena opción (lo más seguro es que no lo sea) y plantearte la estructura de tu sistema y la razón por la que necesitas hacerlo así.

Comment: variables locales, estas me sirven para enviar datos de un formulario estático!

Comment: por que no las hago con un array?-- son demasiadas variables 175 variables para ser exacto!, soy un poco novato en este aspecto! y aun no es dinamicamente

Comment: como te menciona @fabiansilva es mejor hacerlo con un object, para solo crear `store[customName]` para recorrerlo se haria con un `Object.keys(store)` que te dará todos los indices contenidos en la variable y para borrarlos `delete strore[customName]`

Answer (score 0):

Deduzco por este codigo :

```
 var (con[k]+i+i)=document.getElementById(con[k]+i+i).value;
```

Que la variable se debe llamar igual que el valor que almacena, en este caso `(con[k]+i+i)`.

Puedes realizarlo con el objeto window:

`window[nombreVariable] = "valor";
alert(nombreVariable);`

Answer (score 0):

si usas un objeto le puedes asignar propiedades dinamicamente

```
var scope = {}
for (var i=1;i<=20;i++) {
  scope['a'+i] = 'stuff';   
}
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13786987/251626

el tema es como luego accederas a esas propiedades....

lo mejor es como decia un comentario, que crees un array y asignes a ese array los valores, para luego poder consultarlos de una mejor manera